# How can I add minor modes to the temporary buffers used to edit org-src-blocks?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to chose which extra-modes would be turned on in temporary buffers, which are dedicated to editing code, through `org-edit-special` (`C-x '`).

For an example, `auto-complete-mode` and `rainbow-delimiters-mode` in every `org-edit-special buffer` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-edit-special` turns on `org-src-mode`, a minor mode, whose mode hook is called when entering (or exiting) the mode. So you can turn on your minor modes in the `org-src-mode` hook:

```
(add-to-hook 'org-src-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-complete-mode 1) (rainbow-delimiters-mode 1) ...))
```

The doc string for `org-src-mode-hook` says:

```
org-src-mode-hook is a variable defined in ‘org-src.el’.

Its value is
(org-src-babel-configure-edit-buffer org-src-mode-configure-edit-buffer)
Original value was nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
  You can customize this variable.

Hook run after Org switched a source code snippet to its Emacs mode.

This hook will run:
- when editing a source code snippet with ‘C-c '’
- when formatting a source code snippet for export with htmlize.

You may want to use this hook for example to turn off ‘outline-minor-mode’
or similar things which you want to have when editing a source code file,
but which mess up the display of a snippet in Org exported files.
```

Untested, but (dare I say it?) it should work :-)